# Render Point Clouds with Three.js in Autodesk Forge using BufferGeometry

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm trying to render point clouds using Autodesk Forge's viewer. This works fine using `THREE.Geometry` as described here https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/using-pointcloud-forge-viewer. In this article it is specified that one cannot use BufferGeometry.

However, I want to be absolutely sure if there's any way of using PointCloud with BufferGeometry without having to create a `THREE.Geometry`. I already have the data as `Float32Array` for the points and `Uint8Array` for colors so putting them in `THREE.Vector3`s feels like a lot of overhead here.

Looking through the source https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/viewer3D.js there's some mention of point cloud buffers, (search for `createPointCloudBuffers(geometry)`.

**Edit:**

When trying to use THREE.BufferGeometry with `THREE.PointCloud` with:

```
const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(position, 3));
geometry.addAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(color, 3));
const pc = THREE.PointCloud(geometry, <material>);
```

I'm getting the following message:

`Only THREE.Mesh can be rendered by the Firefly renderer. Use THREE.Mesh to draw lines.` (Look at renderBufferDirect function in https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/viewer3D.js)

**Edit 2**: Thanks to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53228664/render-point-clouds-with-three-js-in-autodesk-forge-using-buffergeometry#comment94020827_53235876) I was able to fix the above problem. I simply had to use a `THREE.Mesh` and set `isPoints=true`:

```
const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(position, 3));
geometry.addAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(color, 3));
geometry.isPoints = true;
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, <material>);
```

However, some of the position data I have, as well the color data is saved as `Uint8Array`, and the above would then cause the following error with WebGL:

```
ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 0
```

Converting to `Float32Array` would fix the problem. It would be nice to go through this extra step, is there any way of using Uint8Array without having go through copying it to a Float32Array (using `Float32Array.from(<Uint8Array>)`)?

**Edit 3:**

I realized it's possible support `Uint8Array` and `Uint16Array` doing the following:

```
geometry.attributes.position.bytesPerItem = <1 | 2>; // set 1 for Uint8Arrays and 2 for Uint16
geometry.attributes.position.normalize = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be in luck!  Looking at THREE r71 code https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/three.js

you can find the point cloud implementation by searching for the text...

`THREE.PointCloud = function ( geometry, material ) {`

notice the input is `this.geometry`.  Now scroll down a few lines down, to find code that shows support for `THREE.BufferGeometry` as well, here...

`if ( geometry instanceof THREE.BufferGeometry ) {`

Modify these lines of code:
https://github.com/wallabyway/markupExt/blob/fcce2940379ffd9dc27065fa8dd9b34cd37f8ef0/docs/markupExt.js#L92-L96

from using 'THREE.Geometry' to 'THREE.BufferGeometry'

like this...

```
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
var vertices = new Float32Array( [  -1.0, -1.0,  1.0, etc ]);
geometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( vertices, 3 ) );
geometry.addAttribute( 'color', new THREE.BufferAttribute( vertices, 3 ) );
```

Essentially modifying this example to use BufferGeometry...
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/3d-markup-icons-and-info-card

[image]

Let me know if that helps

Comment: Thanks. Have you actually got it working though ? I've tried this, but I'm getting the following: `Only THREE.Mesh can be rendered by the Firefly renderer. Use THREE.Mesh to draw lines.` (Look for relevant code in https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/viewer3D.js)

Comment: ah, now I see.  Let me ask the team and find out if there is a workaround (and possibly future support coming)...

Comment: Thanks Michael, that would be great! Not being able to use BufferGeometry for point clouds makes our webapp quite slow since we need to convert the buffers we have into THREE.Vector3D vertices etc before rendering

Comment: Can you try this...?
... use the THREE.Mesh object and set 'isPoints' to true on the BufferGeometry

Comment: This worked! Thanks a lot! There's however still an issue with this compared to using newer THREE.js: I was not able to use Uint16Array in BufferAttributes, and thus I needed to convert to Float32Array in order to use it

Comment: Glad to hear.  I'll check on U16A instead of F32A, hold on.

Comment: you could try converting it in the vertex shader.  I don’t know of any restrictions on the position attribute that would prevent it.

Comment: Already tried converting in vertex shader, but it fails with `ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 0`. It looks like it's hard coded to using Floats, i.e. 4 bytes (search for this `_gl.vertexAttribPointer(programAttribute, size, _gl.FLOAT, false, 0, startIndex * size * 4); // 4 bytes per Float32` in https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/viewer3D.js)

Comment: Ah, I see.   So, if you modify gl.float to an Uint type, does it work for your buffer input ?  You will need to modify viewer3d.js (use resource redirect chrome extension for debugging).   You might need to put it behind a flag.  If that works, then I can suggest this to the viewer team as a pull request into the next release.  Would that work for you?

Comment: Tnx, I'll try this out soon and let you know.

Comment: Just had a second look into viewer3D.js. Looks like it's not hard coded after all. Setting `bytesPerItem` and `normalize` appropriately on the geometry's attributes did the trick!